# Bing Webmaster Tools does nothing when I try to Upload My Sitemap--- spins & goes back to Submit state

Tags: bing-webmaster-tools

Bing Webmaster Tools does nothing when I try to Upload My Sitemap

The interface literally does nothing, giving me only a spinner, no error message, and no indication what went wrong.

[image]

I am also getting the same problem on GSC so maybe something is wrong with the XML but it looks right to me

https://helios-public-assets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Did you try to upload the xml file through the *.shop* domain?

Comment: disable browser plugins, open the JS console and try again while paying attention to messages in the console. It may give more insight.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler --  yes this works, but is very disappointing because it violates the 12-factor principles--- if I have many dynos (or servers), I shouldn't have to do extra work to keep all of my sitemap.xml files in sync across them. The whole point of having it be hosted remotely is that I could delegate the job of updating the XML to a cron task and know that whenever Google or Bing needs it they just go to the remote bucket (the one place it lives). Now I have to invent a caching mechanism to store my XML file(!) which is an outrageous amount of work to put on us with this change.

Comment: my shock is because this has been the standard way to build Rails apps on 12-factory depoys for 15 years and this is the first time I've heard of this not working: https://simonsomlai.com/en/how-to-create-an-automatic-sitemap-for-your-rails-app-on-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the sitemap isn't hosted on your own domain.  The S3 bucket has an Amazon URL. This is called a "cross-site" sitemap submission.

[Bing now supports cross-site sitemaps](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2008/02/27/microsoft-to-support-cross-domain-sitemaps) but there is only one way to submit them.  You have to list them in `robots.txt` with a line like `sitemap: https://example.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sitemap.xml` rather than submitting through webmaster tools. Even then all the URLs in the sitemap must match the domain of the `robots.txt` file.